# Oracle Enterprise Manager Could Not Complete Configuration

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I'm running 11g R2 on Solaris and EM looks to not have installed. When I try and create the repository manually

```
emca -config dbcontrol db -repos create
```

I get the following message:

```
Sep 16, 2013 1:00:32 PM oracle.sysman.emcp.EMConfig perform
SEVERE:

Database connection through listener failed. Fix the error and run EM Configuration Assistant again.
```

Some of the possible reasons may be:

1. Listener port 1521 provided is incorrect. Provide the correct port.
2. Listener is not up. Start the Listener.
3. Database service dbservice is not registered with listener. Register the database service.
4. Listener is up on physical host and ORACLE_HOSTNAME environment variable is set to virtual host. Unset ORACLE_HOSTNAME environment variable.
5. Listener is up on virtual host. Set environment variable ORACLE_HOSTNAME=.
6. /etc/hosts does not have correct entry for hostname.

Refer to the log file at `/u01/app/oracle/cfgtoollogs/emca/database/emca_2013_09_16_12_58_54.log` for more details.

Could not complete the configuration. Refer to the log file at `/u01/app/oracle/cfgtoollogs/emca/database/emca_2013_09_16_12_58_54.log` for more details.

The log file basically states the same thing.

```
Database connection through listener failed. Fix the error and run EM Configuration Assistant again.
```

Some of the possible reasons may be:

1. Listener port 1521 provided is incorrect. Provide the correct port.
2. Listener is not up. Start the Listener.
3. Database service `dbservice` is not registered with listener. Register the database service.
4. Listener is up on physical host and `ORACLE_HOSTNAME` environment variable is set to virtual host. Unset `ORACLE_HOSTNAME` environment variable.
5. Listener is up on virtual host. Set environment variable `ORACLE_HOSTNAME=<virtual host>`.
6. `/etc/hosts` does not have correct entry for hostname.

   ```
       at oracle.sysman.emcp.ParamsManager.checkListenerStatusForDBControl(ParamsManager.java:3342)
       at oracle.sysman.emcp.EMDBPreConfig.performConfiguration(EMDBPreConfig.java:858)
       at oracle.sysman.emcp.EMDBPreConfig.invoke(EMDBPreConfig.java:288)
       at oracle.sysman.emcp.EMDBPreConfig.invoke(EMDBPreConfig.java:198)
       at oracle.sysman.emcp.EMConfig.perform(EMConfig.java:250)
       at oracle.sysman.emcp.EMConfigAssistant.invokeEMCA(EMConfigAssistant.java:599)
       at oracle.sysman.emcp.EMConfigAssistant.performConfiguration(EMConfigAssistant.java:1482)
       at oracle.sysman.emcp.EMConfigAssistant.statusMain(EMConfigAssistant.java:583)
       at oracle.sysman.emcp.EMConfigAssistant.main(EMConfigAssistant.java:529)
   ```

   Sep 16, 2013 1:00:32 PM oracle.sysman.emcp.EMConfig restoreOuiLoc
   CONFIG: Restoring oracle.installer.oui_loc to /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/oui

The listener port is 1521.

Answer (score 0):

My way:

```
emca -config dbcontrol db
```